# How to use jQuery to overide a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a toggle function when a user clicks a button it adds a class attribute that turns the arrows pointing down. Like the picture below:
[image]

My HTML:

```
<div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="slide1 tab">
                            <h2 class="button">Is a bonus work taking?</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="slide2 tab">
                            <h2 class="button">How does it work?</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="slide3 tab">
                            <h2 class="button">Chances of redeeming bonus </h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="slide4 tab">
                            <h2 class="button">Required documents</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.button {
    background: url(https://preview.c9users.io/jafar70/harry/img/arrowhead-pointing-to-the-right.png) no-repeat right center #DC7228;
    background-position: 98% 50%; 
    margin-right: 200px !important;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0 0 !important;
    padding: 1em 1em;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 13px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.open-button {
    background: url(https://preview.c9users.io/jafar70/harry/img/caret-down.png) no-repeat right center #DC7228 !important;
    background-position: 98% 50%; 
    margin-right: 200px !important;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0 0 !important;
    padding: 1em 1em;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 13px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

My jQuery:

```
$('.tab > .button').click(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('.button').addClass('.open-button');
    });
```

The codepen is https://codepen.io/mrsalami/pen/VdZBgE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, all the jQuery functions that add/remove/alter classes in any way don't require a `.` prefix, so:

```
$(this).removeClass('.button').addClass('.open-button');
```

should be:

```
$(this).removeClass('button').addClass('open-button');
```

Then, to get it to add and then remove on each click you're going to want to use [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) instead:

```
$(this).toggleClass('button').toggleClass('open-button');
```

Or in one call by doing:

```
$(this).toggleClass('button open-button');
```

[Here's a fork of your codepen that is working with that line edited](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YvKOKB)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to remote the dots from the jQuery class methods, so addClass(".button") should be addclass("button"). Seems confusing at first, but it's the ways it works.

For less redundancy, and more DRY, do it like this:

```
$(this).toggleClass('open-button');
```

This way your CSS style for .open-button only needs to change the carat, not repeat the entire styling of the .button class.

[Source](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)